# Why Does Manual Cache Clear Work But CP Task Fails?

Tags: cache

I've been having a problem with my site not properly clearing out its template caches. The task list gets stuck on "Pending" when trying to execute the "Deleting stale template caches" task.

If I manually clear the caches by going to Utilities -> Clear Caches, that works fine and it unblocks the pending task list.

I thought maybe the problem was that my PHP `memory_limit` was too low, but if that were the case wouldn't the manual cache clear command also cause a timeout error?

My `memory_limit` is already pretty high at `512M` so I'm hoping there's an alternative solution to this that won't require me to remove my cache tags.

Answer (score 1):

It's a fairly common problem: https://craftcms.com/guides/resolving-stalled-background-tasks